# Is it possible to define different behaviour for generic types depending on which typeclasses are implemented?

Tags: haskell

There is actually an extra layer to what I'm trying to ask, but the wording is a bit awkward. Here's an example using the `YesNo` typeclass from "Learn You a Haskell".

```
class YesNo a where
    yesno :: a -> Bool

instance YesNo Bool where
    yesno = id

instance YesNo [a] where
    yesno lst = length lst > 0
```

Here, the generic type is `[a]`. Could this code be changed so that `yesno` uses different logic (e.g. returns `False`) when `a` implements `YesNo`?

Comment: So, you mean separating the case of `instance YesNo a => YesNo [a]` from the case where `a` isn't an instance of `YesNo`?

Comment: I'm almost positive that it's not possible, because constraints aren't checked when it does the duplicate instance check but I want to see if someone has a better way to explain it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The typical, and usually best, thing to do when you have a need for type classes to behave differently based on a contained element is to actually make a newtype wrapper and manually wrap the list up at the call site.

The newtype declarations would look like:

```
newtype AllOf a = AllOf { unAllOf :: [a] }

newtype AnyOf a = AnyOf { unAnyOf :: [a] }
```

And, unsurprisingly, the instances use `all` or `any` on the underlying list:

```
instance YesNo a => YesNo (AllOf a) where
    yesno = all yesno . unAllOf


instance YesNo a => YesNo (AnyOf a) where
    yesno = any yesno . unAnyOf
```

Then when you want to use the instance:

```
*Main> yesno (AllOf [True, True, False, True])
False
*Main> yesno (AnyOf [True, True, False, True])
True
```